# Stream API sorted/foreach

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        Stream.of(s.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]+"))
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByKey())/*.thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())*/
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getKey()));

    }
```

Есть данный код. Суть его такова - пишем в консоль слова через пробел, а программа ищет наиболее часто встречающиеся слова и выводит их в порядке от тех, что встречаются чаще, до тех, что встречаются реже. Также стоит лимит на 10 слов. В случае если несколько слов встречаются одинаковое количество раз, они дополнительно сортируются по алфавиту.

> А теперь вопрос - меня беспокоит 2 места в коде:
>
> 1) можно ли как-то отсортировать вывод в одной строке? Я пытался (код
>   закоменченный) через thenComparing, но почему-то с такой реализацией
>   сортируется только по алфавиту.
>
> 2) я хочу вывести слова через ссылку на метод System.out::println,
>   подскажите пожалуйста, как можно разбить поток пар ключ/значение так,
>   чтобы в потоке остались только ключи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Первой нужно указать сортировку по количеству слов, а в `thenComparing` - по алфивиту

```
Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
```

2) Можно добавить map, в котором будет вызываться `getKey`:

```
map(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

Все вместе будет выглядеть как-то так

```
 Stream.of(s.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]+"))
     .map(String::toLowerCase)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
     .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
     .limit(10)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ох, благодарю) от такого кода получаешь истинное эстетическое удовольствие) 
Еще один маленький вопрос. Почему comparingByValue() требует параметризацию, а comparingByKey() не требует?

Comment: исключительно из-за thenComparing. Вот здесь довольно неплохо расписано, почему так происходит https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference

Comment: Спасибо большое)